# Set choice command choices from varable

Tags: batch-file

I would like to use a variable to set choices for the choice command but every time i use this code in a batch file, this is what it outputs
*ERROR: Invalid choice. The valid choice characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.*

```
set 1=1
set 2=2
set 3=3
choice /c %1%%2%%3% /n
if %errorlevel%==1 goto 1
if %errorlevel%==2 goto 2
if %errorlevel%==3 goto 3
```

What am i doing wrong here? 
Help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: If you run your script from the command prompt, you'll clearly see what's happening. Then you'll learn not to use numbers as variable names. `choice /c %2%3 /n`  I'll assume.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify that, you'll learn not to use them as the first character of a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use numeric variable names. You also do not need to do `if errorlevel` as you can simply `goto` in this instance, again I just added `var` before `%errorlevel%` to simply not use numerical characters only..

```
set "var1=1"
set "var2=2"
set "var3=3"
choice /c %var1%%var2%%var3% /n
goto var%errorlevel%

:var1
echo you chose var%errorlevel%
```