# How do I check if "set /p" answer is invalid?

Tags: batch-file

I need to check if %test% is not equal to Y or N, how can I do that?

```
set /p test=
if /i %test% equ Y goto y
if /i %test% equ N goto n
```

Comment: I suggest to read my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) and [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the value supplied does not pass the tests, then it must be not-(y,Y,n,N) so batch simply proceeds to the next instruction. No specific test is required.

But - please consider `choice` which is designed for this task. Use the `search` facility for `[batch-file] choice` eg [Gerhard's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370914/2128947) or see the documentation - `choice /?` from the prompt.

In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.