# How to echo a message an an array on the same line in batch?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file, set, echo

Im getting the list of disk on my computer :

```
REM lister les disques
:list_disk
    ECHO Liste des disques

    set n=0
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID^') do (
       set nom[!n!]=%%a
       set /A n+=1
    )
    set /A "N=%n%/2"
    FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO  (
    echo !nom[%%i]!
    echo/

    )
EXIT /B 0
```

As you can see the discks ID are in an array.

Now I want to give the oportunity to the scipt user to chose or not a disk.

```
REM choix des disque
:choix nom
    echo choix
    set n=0
    set /A "N=%n%/2"
    SET c=n
    FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO  (
       echo voulez vous relever le disque !nom[%%i]! (o/n) ?

       SET /P c=
       if c==o
       rem call :HASH !nom[%%i]!

EXIT /B 0
```

Im trying to `echo message !nom[%%i]!`

but its doesn't work.

How would you do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO  (
   echo voulez vous relever le disque !nom[%%i]! (o/n^) ?

   SET c=n
   SET /P c=
   if !c!==o ECHO call :HASH !nom[%%i]!
)
```

should cure your problem (as I see it)

The caret `^` must be included to "escape" the `)` otherwise the `)` in the message will close the `do (`.

And then you're missing a `)` to close the `do (`.
You need to set `c` to `n` each time you prompt otherwise it will retain its value from when it was last set.

The `if` statement is incomplete and must attempt to match `!c!` which is the value of variable `c` after the `set` has been responded to.

`c` will never be equal to `o`.

You can use `if /i...` to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Please consider `choice` which is designed for this task. Use the search facility for [batch-file] choice eg Gerhard's example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370914/2128947 or see the documentation - `choice /?` from the prompt.

---

Run log

```
voulez vous relever le disque Q (o/n) ?
o
call :HASH Q
voulez vous relever le disque W (o/n) ?
n
voulez vous relever le disque X (o/n) ?
o
call :HASH X
U:\>
```

Comment: its printing this for me `(o/n) ?ous relever le disque C:`. why ? every thing after the variable is puted at the bigining.

Comment: I suspect that your editor is saving the code as unicode or perhaps with unix line-endings.  Batch files should be saved as ANSI with <CR><LF> line endings. I use `editplus` as an editor, others use `notepad++` - these are popular selections for editors. `Notepad` or a word-processor may save in an unwanted manner.

Comment: Ok im editing my code on pycharm and I interpret my code with cmd on windows.

Comment: im also using CRLF UTF8

Comment: Batch files should be saved as ANSI with <CR><LF> line endings, not UTF8. I've appended the response from my system using the above batch code, saved as ANSI with <CR><LF>

Comment: The biggest issue is answered so i will close the ticket, but I'm still struggling with printing after a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I prepared earlier for generating menu's from command output.

The below script defines a Macro that when expanded captures the output of the subsequent command, builds the output into a list of choices for selection by a user, the value of which is returned in the variable declared as argument 1 when the macro is defined. Additional arguments can be provided to tokenize and deliminate the output - useage is described in the codes remarks.

The below script demonstrates the definition call of the macro and expansion with command relevant to your use case.

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 CLS

Rem Arg 1 defines macro suffix for expansion and return variable. Args 2 + 3 override default macro token and delim definition.
 Call:DefMenuMacro [WMICdrive] 2 "="

 %Menu[WMICdrive]%wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID /Value
 Set [WMICdrive]

 Pause

Endlocal & Goto:Eof

======================================================================
:DefMenuMacro <MENUNAME> [tokens] [Delims]

If "%~2" == "" (
    set "Menu.Tokens=*"
)Else set "Menu.Tokens=%~2"

If "%~3" == "" (
    set "Menu.Delims="
)Else set "Menu.Delims=%~3"

(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify. =%)
 Set LF=^


Rem above empty lines required

:# Menu macro Definition requires environment with DelayedExpansion DISabled
 If "!!" == "" Exit /B 1

:# Key index list Allows 36 menu Menu.Options. Component of Menu Macro
 Set "Menu.List=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

:# Menu macro Usage: %MenuMENUNAME%command
==== Set Menu%~1=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                        =%  If not defined Menu.First Echo(!Menu.Div!%\n%
%= Reset Menu.opt# index value for Menu.Opt[#] =%  Set "Menu.opt#=0"%\n%
%= Undefine choice option key list             =%  Set "Menu.Chars="%\n%
%= For Each in list;                           =%  For /F "UsebackQ Tokens=%Menu.Tokens% Delims=^%Menu.Delims%" %%F in (`!Command.Output!`)Do For /f "Delims=" %%G in ("%%F")Do If not "%%~G" == "!LF!" (%\n%
%= For Option Index value                      =%   For %%i in (!Menu.opt#!)Do IF not %%i GTR 35 (%\n%
%= Build the Choice key list and Menu.Opt[#]   =%    Set "Menu.Chars=!Menu.Chars!!Menu.List:~%%i,1!"%\n%
%= array using the character at the            =%    Set "Menu.Opt[!Menu.List:~%%i,1!]=%%~G"%\n%
%= current substring index.                    =%    Set "Menu.Display=%%~G"%\n%
%= Display ; removing # variable prefix        =%    Echo([!Menu.List:~%%i,1!] !Menu.Display:#=!%\n%
%= Increment Menu.Opt[#] Index var 'Menu.opt#' =%    Set /A "Menu.opt#+=1"%\n%
%= Close Menu.opt# loop                        =%   )%\n%
%= Close Menu.options loop                     =%  )%\n%
%= Output Menu.Dividing Line                   =%  Echo(!Menu.Div!%\n%
%= Select option by character index            =%  For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('Choice /N /C:!Menu.Chars!')Do (%\n%
%= Assign return var 'OPTION' with the         =%   Set "%~1=!Menu.Opt[%%o]!"%\n%
%=                                             =%  )%\n%
%= Return option accross endlocal              =%  For %%v in ("!%~1!")Do Endlocal ^& (%\n%
                                                    Set "%~1=%%~v"%\n%
                                                   )%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Menu.Options List     =% )Else Setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set Command.Output=
========================================== ::: End Menu Definition
Exit /b 0
```

Comment: can you edit your answer I dont see how relevent your code is....

Comment: @akmot additional description added