# How can I call something up and return to where I called it from in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I'm at `:Forest`, for example, how I can type `I`, to display the Inventory, and then return to where I called it from?

Example snippet:

```
:Inventory
echo Inventory:
echo bla bla items
cls
pause

:StoryBegin
echo This is a story
set /p input=(1,2)?
if %input% == 1 goto Forest
if %input% == 2 goto Castle
if %input% == I goto Inventory

:Forest
set /p input=(1,2)
if %input% == 1 goto House
if %input% == 2 goto Hill
if %input% == I goto Inventory
```

Comment: To highlight code, select the code and press the `{}` button

Comment: There is a command to call a subroutine. Surprisingly, its name is `call`

Answer (score 0):

Please consider `choice` which is designed for this task. Use the search facility for [batch-file] choice eg Gerhard's example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370914/2128947 or see the documentation - `choice /?` from the prompt.

The magic formula from there is

```
if errorlevel x call :inventory&goto somewhere
```

Where `:inventory` is an "internal subroutine" which should terminate with a `goto :eof`. The colons in the `call` statement and `goto :eof` are required.