# Always get invalid entry message

Tags: batch-file

each time someone enters C,c,D or d they still get the invalid entry message even tho its valid

```
@echo OFF 
Echo Bienvenido
Echo.
echo Este batch es para saber si quieres Disk Clean Up o desea hacer un Disk Defragmenter
echo.
pause
cls
echo. 
set C= DiskCleanUp
set D= DiskDeFragmenter
:menu
echo --------------------------------------
echo Escoge C para cleanup o D para Defrag 
echo --------------------------------------
set /p Option= Ingrese C o D:
echo -------------------------
:choice
If %Option%== C start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe Else goto :incorrect
If %Option%== c start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe Else goto :incorrect
If %Option%== D start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe Else goto :incorrect
If %Option%== d start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe Else goto :incorrect
:incorrect
    cls
    echo.
    echo Invalid Entry
    pause
    goto :menu

echo. 
cls
Echo Gracias por usar este batch de Eduardo Figueroa.
echo.
echo Press Enter para cerrar.
echo . 
pause
echo.
Exit
```

each time someone enters C,c,D or d they still get the invalid entry message even tho its valid

Comment: The spaces in `If %Option%== C` (and the others) are getting included in the comparison, so you need to remove them. Also, you should be using quotes around both things in case the user doesn't enter anything. `If "%Option%"=="C"`. Also also, you can use the `/I` flag so that you can do a case-insensitive comparison. `If /I "%Option%"=="C"`. Also also also, every single `else` part there needs to be removed because once you get the `if` statement corrected, literally anything that isn't `C` will be considered incorrect because the first `if` is returning false so it goes to `:incorrect.`

Comment: ok I fixed everything you said and it makes it MUUUUCH BETTER!!! but even i type in C and it opens disk clean up i still get invalid entry message from :incorrect no matter what i so the incorrect message always shows up! example

i enter C it open the disk cleaner and also gives invalid entry message and if i press any key it goes back to :menu

Comment: You have to remember that labels are just signposts and don't actually stop the flow of the script from continuing. If you want the script to go somewhere else after starting `cleanmgr` or `dfrgui`, then you need another command to tell the script to go there.

Comment: could i get an example i change this and it still doesnt work
If /I "%Option%"=="C" start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe goto :Correct
If /I "%Option%"=="D" start %windir%\system32\dfrgui.exe goto :Correct

:incorrect
    cls
    echo.
    echo Invalid Entry
    pause
    goto :menu


:Correct

Comment: You'd usually use parentheses to run multiple commands, like `if /I "%option%"=="C" (` and then `start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe` and then `goto :Correct` and then `)`, with each of those four things being on a separate line.

Comment: @SomethingDark : "The spaces in If %Option%== C (and the others) are getting included in the comparison, " Oh no they're not, dark one! The parsing logic for an `if` comparison statement is very specific; `if [/i][ NOT] arg1 op arg2` where `/i` and ` not` are optional, but **must** if used, be used in that order. `op` may be any of `==`, `neq`, `equ`, `gtr`, `geq`, `lss`, `leq`. The separators are normally spaces, but may be any separator. A separator is required before `not` and on both sides of any operator except "==".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for this statement

```
If %Option%== C start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe Else goto :incorrect
```

if `Option` has been set to `C`, then what is executed is

```
start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe Else goto :incorrect
```

`else` is simply a string. To do what was intended by that statement, you need

```
If %Option%== C (start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe) Else (goto :incorrect)
```

This tells `cmd` that `(start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe)` is what to do if the comparison yields `true`, and `(goto :incorrect)` is what to do if the comparison yields `false`.

Note that the colon is **not** required. (IMHO, for `goto`, the colon should **only** be used in a `goto :eof` statement, where `:eof` has the defined meaning `end-of-file`)

The problen with making this correction is that if `%option%` is not `C`, then you execute the `else` part, and proceed to `:incorrect`. The way to fix *that* is to remove the `else` clause entirely, leaving

```
If %Option%== C (start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe)
```

where the parentheses are not required since just one statement is being executed.

Even with all the statements modified to the pattern

```
If %Option%== C start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe
```

and the `/i` option applied, the batch would then "flow through" to the label `:incorrect` and produce the error message since it's not told to `goto menu` if C/D is chosen.

Therefore you need

```
If %Option%== C start %windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe&goto menu
```

where `&` separates a series of commands.

Next a couple of tips, for peace in batch-land.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Please consider `choice` which is designed for this task. Use the search facility for [batch-file] choice eg Gerhard's example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370914/2128947 or see the documentation - `choice /?` from the prompt.