# batch. if/else statements. wanting to go back if say user doesnt input and only presses enter

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, user-input

If a user were to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then the `else` portion of the statement is ignored and the process ends and closes.

```bash
:options
cls
echo. 
echo What would you like to do?
echo. 
pause\>nul

echo 1) Main Menu
echo 2) Controls
echo 3) Introduction 
echo 4) exit 

set "choice="
set/p choice=choice: 
pause \>nul

if %choice%== 1 goto mainmenu 
if %choice%== 2 goto Controls
if %choice%== 3 goto introduction
if %choice%== 4 goto eof1
if not defined "%choice%"=="" ( 
    
) else (
    
) goto options
```

I would prefer not to use the `choice` command.

Comment: Please consider `choice` which is designed for this task. Use the search facility for `[batch-file] choice` eg. [Gerhard's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370914/2128947) or see the documentation - `choice /?` from the prompt.. With your code, `if not defined "%choice%"=="" (` is completely wrong - `if not defined choice ( `would take the action if the response was `[enter]`. `if "%choice%"=="" (` would do the same.

Answer (score -1):

A Quick and short answer is

if "%choice%" == " " call :options

Just a question and suggestion about the options below

:options
cls
echo.
echo What would you like to do?
echo.
pause>nul      <--------------- why use pause?

when set /p does the same ? for a better look try using TITLE to output "what would you like to do" which cleans up the menu and places the question in the border title bar.

like:

TITLE="What would you like to do ?"
also put your set here

set choice=    (to clear the last choice )

echo 1) Main Menu

echo 2) Controls

echo 3) Introduction

echo 4) exit

set /p choice=choice:

if %choice% == 1 goto mainmenu

if %choice% == 2 goto Controls

if %choice% == 3 goto introduction

if %choice% == 4 goto eof1

if not defined "%choice%" (
call :options
) else (
exit /b
)